# How do you compare today's date with the date provided by Django using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: jquery, django

The whole problem is to compare the date extracted from the database and passed to the input field in the template with today's date generated by jquery.

Unfortunately when I tried print startDt console return me "undefined value"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let endDt = new Date();

  $(".date").each(function() {
    let startDt= $(this).attr('data-book').val;
    if ((new Date(startDt).getTime() < new Date(endDt).getTime())) {
      // Rest of code here
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="date" class="date" hidden data-book="{{ book.slug }}" value="{{ book.date|date:" Y-m-d " }}">
```

Comment: Please show the actual output from Django in the HTML, as the Django code itself is not immediately relevant. Also, what is `startDt`?

Comment: django returns something like this: '2020-03-18'

Comment: What do you expect this statement to do "let startDt= $(this).attr('data-book').val;" @Pilaverci

Comment: Do you want the value of this input field   "<input type="date" class="date" hidden data-book="{{ book.slug }}" value="{{ book.date|date:" Y-m-d " }}">"  ??? @Pilaverci

Comment: Yes, exackly, I expect, that it return date. The whole idea is to compare two dates, maybe way what I choose isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is almost there. The issue is with the way you're retrieving the attributes from the element.

To fill the `startDt` variable you need to invoke the `val()` method (including parentheses). `attr('data-book')` is not required (and if it was it should be `data('book')` instead).

Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let endDt = new Date();

  $(".date").each(function() {
    let startDt = $(this).val();
    if ((new Date(startDt).getTime() < new Date(endDt).getTime())) {
      console.log('start is BEFORE end');
    } else {
      console.log('start is AFTER end');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date" hidden data-book="{{ book.slug }}" value="2020-03-18">
<input type="date" class="date" hidden data-book="{{ book.slug }}" value="2018-03-18">
<input type="date" class="date" hidden data-book="{{ book.slug }}" value="2050-03-18">
```

Comment: I should do it earlier but I completly forgot about it, on the one webside is more than one item with class date (all of them are generateg automaticly so I couldn't give them unique id), so attr('data-book') is necessary to tell them apart, moreover date isn't static too, so I can't write only '' 2020-03-18 ''

Comment: That's fine, but this code works for an infinite number of inputs. See the edit I made